# Mysql SEC_TO_TIME generates error

Tags: mysql

When trying to execute the following SQL:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(edate,sdate))-rast)+3600) as TotalDiff from tblregtime where userID IN(97,41) AND year(sdate)=2012
```

it returns this error:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

The problem only occurs when the sum of totalDiff exceeds 24hours. Any suggestions why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I'd say there's nothing to do with mysql but your driver or the way you use it.

Comment: I think that negative values are getting passed to SEC_TO_TIME or TIME_TO_SEC function.

Comment: when running the SQL directly against the database im getting the right output. Its when i trying to execute the SQL when running the website that im getting the error. (using mysql odbc 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

[SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time): The range of the result is constrained to that of the TIME data type. A warning occurs if the argument corresponds to a value outside that range.

[TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html): TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.

Is it possible that `sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(edate,sdate))-rast)+3600` is outside the stated range?

*(Definitions courtesy of the online [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html)).*

Comment: add code to your web app to print out the value of each of the parts (edate, sdate, rast), maybe even perform portions of the query TIMEDIFF(edate, sdate) -- TIME_TO_SEC ... and print those out as well ... check to see what these values are when the error occurs. After all, it must be SOMETHING!!